# Using ProcMon on Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 project that refers to a Windows Runtime Component, which exposes some other native projects of mine. The problem is I get a System.IO.FileNotFoundException when running it on emulator. However, if I catch the exception and check exception.FileName, it's null.

The guy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555318/cant-load-winrt-component-unless-i-reference-the-project) has mentioned he used ProcMon to figure out which file was missing. How do I use ProcMon to monitor file accesses made by an emulator? I tried monitoring the emulator process itself, but that didn't produce any info.

Comment: At least a comment for the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way provided to run desktop apps such as ProcMon on the emulator. The linked post was able to run ProcMon on Windows, not on Windows Phone.

Your best bet is to debug the app running on the emulator. Use the unmanaged debugger so it can break in the native code, break on the first chance exception, then see where in the stack this is called from. Once you know where the problem is, you can set a break point at the beginning of the function then either step through or set a trace point to see what files are being used and what the app thinks it is doing then.