# Cant load WinRT/C++ component to my UWP/C# application

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, c++-cx, winrt-component

I need to wrap WebRTC c++ library into WinRT component and use it from my UWP/C# application.
There is a good article [how to use native c++ in uwp](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2019/use-native-cplusplus-in-uwp/) which describes all the integration steps, which I followed.
Briefly:

- I have created Dll/C++ `DLL1` library and linked my static library `libwebrtc_full.a`. Made all necessary calls
- Then, I referenced the DLL in my WinRT/C++ project `WindowsRuntimeComponent1` and created public ref class `MyClass` successfully which makes all the necessary calls from `DLL1`
- My UWP app `App1` sees `MyClass` correctly and its public methods, `App1` has reference to the WindowsRuntimeComponent.

When it comes to run the application, I am getting runtime exception as soon as I try to use one of the classes implemented in `WindowsRuntimeComponent1`

```
The specified module could not be found.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

I created and uploaded a sample project to reproduce my problem to [GDrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19rpD_UHYR-MJw5LdFrKvXnJMX0-Au_fM/view?usp=sharing) I included my static `libwebrtc.a` as well in the sample project in case if its the root cause of the problem.

I already went through the similar questions on SO and most similar to my problem is this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555318/cant-load-winrt-component-unless-i-reference-the-project). The difference is that I am referencing the project and still get the same exception.

**EDIT1:**

This is how `MyClass` looks like:

```
namespace WindowsRuntimeComponent1
{
    public ref class MyClass sealed
    {
    public:
        MyClass(int sampleRate);
        virtual ~MyClass();

        void ProcessFrame(const Platform::Array<short>^ mic, const Platform::Array<short>^ speaker, const Platform::Array<short>^ output);

    private:
        void* p;
    };
}
```

**EDIT2:**
I ran `gflags App1.exe +sls` as suggested in the comments, but I dont see what dependency is missing. Below is the screenshot with stack trace:

[image]

Comment: *"created public ref class `MyClass`"* - That doesn't sound like C++/WinRT. What programming language are you really using?

Comment: @IInspectable I edited my answer and attached .h of `MyClass` which is CLR, I guess

Comment: There is no CLR in the Windows Runtime. Pretty hard to drive that point home, even ten years after the Windows Runtime was introduced. The programming language you are using is C++/CX. Like C++/WinRT (which you aren't using) this compiles down to native code.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for clarifying this moment. So, is it possible what I am trying to achieve - use C++/CX wrapper class in my UWP/c# project?

Comment: So long as the Windows Runtime Component doesn't use APIs that aren't available for your target platform (UWP) that's perfectly fine. I don't know whether WebRTC provides an implementation that can run on the UWP, and if it doesn't whether this is related to the issue. It's likely, though, that you are simply missing a dependency in your package.

Comment: May I ask you to install the sample project I attached in the question? I can post it to GitHub, if its more convenient for you

Comment: I don't have any .NET workloads installed, so that's not going to work for me. What you can do to investigate further is to [enable loader snaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/show-loader-snaps), and run the application under a debugger. That *might* give you insights into which dependency is failing to load.

Comment: @IInspectable I have run the gflags utility with `+sls` argument, could you please have a look into screenshot, I can not see which dependency is missing

Comment: You need to copy protobuf_lite.dll into the deployment directory (aside app1.exe in bin\x86\Debug\AppX)